# How do I create a list from a series of computed values (scheme)

Tags: scheme

I've created a function that gives a items in a list a certain score

> `(define newlist
>   '((score  'A )
>   (score 'A1 )
>   (score 'A2 )))`

but cannot get it to return a ( X Y Z) list . 
Only

> `'((score   23 )
>   (score  12 )
>   (score   7 ))`
>   
>   which is only the substituted values for my variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `map` function:

```lisp
;if A, A1 and A2 are to be used as symbols:
(define newlist (map score '(A A1 A2)))
;which is equivalent to:
(define newlist (map score (list 'A 'A1 'A2)))

;however, if A, A1 and A2 are variables whose values you wish to use:
(define newlist (map score (list A A1 A2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `quote` (the character `'`) what follows in not evaluated.  So in what you provided, the entire list of three items is not evaluated.  To evaluate use `list` as such:

```
  (define newlist (list (score 'A) (score 'A1) (score 'A2)))
```

As @kmoerman points out, there are other ways, using `map`, to get a valid result; however, your original problem was using `quote` instead of `list`.

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(define newlist `(,(score 'A) ,(score 'A1) ,(score 'A2)))
```